# Erratic behavior with NULL '\0' when printing combinations of letters

Tags: c, null, cs50

My intention with this code is to print all possible combinations between the letters of the alphabet, **including single letters.**I wrote this part of a program from CS50x course (week 2 - crack)

I include the use of `'\0'` in order to get as well the single letters. It all works well until it starts working on the uppercase letters, after then it will skip `'\0'` once every two loops. The result is I am missing half of single uppercase letters and I have no idea why it acts this way.

This is an extract of the result I get (this part is correct, notice single letters 'g', 'h', 'i' all get printed):

> Blockquote fZ      ***g***       ga      gb      gc      gd      ge      gf      gg      gh      gi      gj      gk  gl       gm      gn      go      gp      gq      gr      gs      gt      gu      gv      gw      gx      gy      gz  gA       gB      gC      gD      gE      gF      gG      gH      gI      gJ      gK      gL      gM      gN      gO  gP       gQ      gR      gS      gT      gU      gV      gW      gX      gY      gZ      ***h***       ha      hb      hc  hd       he      hf      hg      hh      hi      hj      hk      hl      hm      hn      ho      hp      hq      hr  hs       ht      hu      hv      hw      hx      hy      hz      hA      hB      hC      hD      hE      hF      hG  hH       hI      hJ      hK      hL      hM      hN      hO      hP      hQ      hR      hS      hT      hU      hV  hW       hX      hY      hZ      ***i***       ia      ib      ic

But after a while it starts skipping letters (it prints 'W' and 'Y' but not 'X')

> Blockquote VZ      ***W***       Wa      Wb      Wc      Wd      We      Wf      Wg  Wh       Wi      Wj      Wk      Wl      Wm      Wn      Wo      Wp      Wq      Wr      Ws      Wt      Wu      Wv  Ww       Wx      Wy      Wz      WA      WB      WC      WD      WE      WF      WG      WH      WI      WJ      WK  WL       WM      WN      WO      WP      WQ      WR      WS      WT      WU      WV      WW      WX      WY      ***WZ  Xa***       Xb      Xc      Xd      Xe      Xf      Xg      Xh      Xi      Xj      Xk      Xl      Xm      Xn      Xo  Xp       Xq      Xr      Xs      Xt      Xu      Xv      Xw      Xx      Xy      Xz      XA      XB      XC      XD  XE       XF      XG      XH      XI      XJ      XK      XL      XM      XN      XO      XP      XQ      XR      XS  XT       XU      XV      XW      XX      XY      XZ      ***Y***       Ya

This is the original code:

```
int main(void)
    {
        char abc[52] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        char xyz[3];
        char null = '\0';

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            xyz[0] = abc[i];
            xyz[1] = null;
            printf("%s  ", xyz);
            for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
            {
                xyz[1] = abc[j];
                printf("%s  ", xyz);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");    
    }'''
```

Comment: You terminated the string with `xyz[1] = null;` before the first printing, but forgot it before the second — `xyz[2] = null;`

Comment: `xyz[2]` must be zero for the array to be considered a string

Comment: While avoiding magic numbers is generally good, some of them are so well-known and in the right context might be better than some symbolic constant or a variable. Using `'\0'` directly instead of your variable `null` is considered okay by almost everyone.

Comment: `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant. The null character `'\0'` is a character value. They're (almost) entirely different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Agreed. Every C programmer of any reasonable level of experience knows what `'\0'` means. If I see `null`, I have to look up how it's defined -- and in this case, I have to verify that it hasn't been modified (since it wasn't defined as `const`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks I realize after your comment is redundant to use a variable to implement '\0' when I can use it directly as in { xyz[1] = '\0';}. I'll keep it in mind to keep things cleaner and more efficient in the future thanks!

Comment: Can't repeat your "missing characters". After making the correction `char xyz[3] = "";` to zero the whole buffer, I get exactly the right file size (redirected output). Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
xyz[1] = abc[j];
```

you overwrite the null terminator you just set.

Better to initialize the whole array to zero (the null terminator)

```
char xyz[3] = { '\0' };
```

Then you don't need to explicitly set a null terminator a second time for the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks, I am not very confident I am understanding the feedback well to apply it.  I tried following the different comments setting also xyz[2] = '\0' and your own to initialize the whole array. But the problem persists: only half the uppercase letters get printed without combining with a second letter (the intention is to get all of them also without combining).  I will edit my own question to show the result I am getting v. what I intend to have. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I moved on to the next week of the course and they introduced an IDE which I used to try on this. As @Weather Vane points out, it works perfectly this time. So I assume the code was not entirely wrong, just somehow the previous sandbox on which I was compiling and running the program may be the problem here. Thanks to all who posted!